# Dead keyboard when entering password

Tags: login, password, command-line

I lost all icon from my desktop. When I use the terminal I am able to enter the commands but the keyboard goes dead when ask for my password. The only key that works is the enter key and after 3 enters it starts over and the keyboard starts to work.  Help, I'm new to Ubuntu and I really like it but been having problem since I upgraded.

Comment: Why do you think so? In Ubuntu, when a terminal request a password, you can press all the keys that you want to but the terminal will not show any character. So that is a normal behavior. Please, check twice that you're entering the correct password.

Comment: Also, where are your icons related with the keyboard problem?

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the keyboard issue.  I'm use to Window where it shows an entry as you type in the PW. All the icons on the desktop are gone when I boot up.  I do get my regular screen theme but I have nothing to navigate to.  Ed

Comment: The keyboard is one issue, and the icons are **another** issue. To solve this last problem, you should [create a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).

Comment: The icons issue *appears* to be [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears).

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu, when a terminal request a password, you can press all the keys that you want to but the terminal *will not show any character* in the password field (neither those popular dots).

So **it is a normal behavior**.

If you still can't connect, you should check the keys that you're pressing.

I left the next screen-shoot, to have a reference:

[image: screenshoot]